# Binary operation argument type string is not compatible with type string

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

My editor (Webstorm) is giving me this weird message:

> Binary operation argument type string is not compatible with type
>   string

Here is the code that is causing the warning message:

```
const {masterid = '', type = ''} = req.query;

if (!masterid) {
    return res.status(500).send(new Error('Missing query param "masterid".'));
}

async.autoInject({

    patients(callback) {
        if(type && type !== 'staff'){
            return process.nextTick(callback);
        }
        store.get(`chat:presence:users:${masterid}`, callback)
    },

    users(callback) {
        if(type && type !== 'patient'){
            return process.nextTick(callback);
        }
        store.get(`chat:presence:patient:${masterid}`, callback);
    }

}, (err, results) => {

    if (err) {
        return res.status(err.code).send(err);
    }

    res.json(results);

});
```

maybe I am using the wrong syntax?

[image]

I am just trying to set default values for the variables..the syntax should be correct.

Comment: Weird. The `!==` operator has higher precedence than `&&` so this should group correctly. What happens if you put parens around the inequality test: `if(type && (type !== 'staff')){`?

Comment: I bet it's just a problem with my editor, it's a static warning not a runtime error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bug, please follow [WEB-33226](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33226) for updates